# Next Auth v5: How to fail the authorization?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'm using magic link to let users authenticate. I have `/auth/magiclogin/callback?token=<some token>` through NextJS 14 app router.

```js
// @/auth/magiclogin/callback/page.tsx


    const [state, setState] = useState(AuthenticateStatus.PENDING)

    useEffect(() => {
        const signIn = async () => {
            try {
                await SignIn(searchParams.token)
                //    ^^^^^^^ this is a server action
            } catch (error) {
                setState(AuthenticateStatus.ERROR)
            }
        }

        signIn()
    }, [])
```

Server action calls `signIn` from next auth.

```js
//@/actions/SignIn.ts
'use server'

import { AuthError } from 'next-auth'
import { signIn } from '../auth'

export const SignIn = async (token: string) => {
    console.log('Sign in action called')
    // add validation here
    try {
        await signIn('credentials', {
            token,
            redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Sign in action failed', error.message)

        if (error instanceof AuthError) {
            switch (error.type) {
                case 'CredentialsSignin': {
                    console.log('error type: CredentialsSignin')
                    return { error: 'Invalid credentials!' }
                }
                default: {
                    console.log('error type: AuthError')
                    return { error: 'Something went wrong!' }
                }
            }
        }

        console.log('error type: unknown')
        return { error: 'something went wrong!' }
    }
}
```

Following is the `auth.ts` file

```js
//@/auth.ts
export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials: Partial<Record<"token", unknown>>) {
        if (!credentials.token || credentials.token.length < 1) {
          return null;
        }
        ...
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      console.log("jwt **********************************", user);
      if (!user) return token;
      token.access_token = user.access_token;
      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log("session **********************************", token);
      session.access_token = token.access_token;
      return session;
    },
  },
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  trustHost: true,
});
```

If the token is empty in the url (`/auth/magiclogin/callback?toke=` then following condition will be `true` and return `null`.

```js
if (!credentials.token || credentials.token.length < 1) {
    return null;
}
```

As a result `jwt` and `session` is never called. An error will be thrown in `SignIn` action. Console logs in SignIn prints `error type: CredentialsSignin`. However, NextAuth dumps long error message also to the console. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/9900#issuecomment-1926145089) it's the expected behavior. In the same thread, [someone said by returning this object](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/9900#issuecomment-1976635550) the error will be handled gracefully.

But following will call `jwt` callbacks.

```
if (!credentials.token || credentials.token.length < 1) {
    return { msg: 'Invalid credentials', status: 'error' }
}
```

In the `SignIn` action, error will be thrown and following is printed.

```
Sign in action called
jwt ********************************** {
  msg: 'Invalid credentials',
  status: 'error',
  id: '44d43fac-3e91-4b04-8b4f-23d768188a11'
}
Sign in action failed NEXT_REDIRECT
error type: unknown
```

In the browser, I can see `authjs.session-token` is also set but when `null` is returned from `authorize`, only `authjs.callback-url` and `authjs.csrf-token` are the only cookies set.

I'm new to NextJs but I expected `jwt` & `session` callbacks not to be called, `authjs.session-token` not to be set, and a clear error message to be available in the catch block of the `SignIn` action (but error.message only includes `NEXT_REDIRECT`).

What am  I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try setting signin({redirect: false}) and call redirect() in finally{}.  see https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/9389 and according to docs here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect  it says "In Server Actions and Route Handlers, redirect should be called after the try/catch block."

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you need a server action to achieve what you want. We can directly use this method to handle the sign in request: https://authjs.dev/reference/nextjs/react#signin

To do this

1. Add a SignInForm.tsx file which is a client component and call it from your page.tsx file. Pass the token value you get from searchParams as a prop.

page.tsx file (path: /app/signin/page.tsx)

```
import React from "react"

import SignInForm from "@/app/components/SignInForm" // e.x.

const PageSignIn = ({
 searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) => {
    const token = searchParams["token"]
    
    return (
        <div className={`nc-PageSignIn`}>
            <!-- code -->
            <SignInForm token={token} />
            <!-- code -->
        </div>
    )
}

export default PageSignIn
```

SignInForm.tsx file (path: /app/components/SignInForm.tsx)

```
"use client"

import React, { useEffect } from "react" 

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

import type { SignInResponse } from "next-auth/lib/client"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"

export default function SignInForm({ token }: any) { // I leave the type part to you
    const router = useRouter()
    async function logIn({ token }: any) {
        signIn("credentials", {
            token,
            redirect: false,
        })
            .then((res: SignInResponse | undefined) => {
                if (!res.ok) alert("Something went wrong!")
                else if (res.error) { 
                    // you can check error type and take action accordingly if you wish
                    alert(`Internal Server Error: ${res.error}`)
                }
                else
                    router.push("/dashboard")
            })
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        logIn(token)
    }, [token])
    
    return (
        <>
            <!-- code -->
        </>
    )
}
```

2. change authorize method like this

```
async authorize(credentials: Partial<Record<"token", unknown>>) {
    if (!credentials.token || credentials.token.length < 1) {
        throw new Error()
    }
    // your code
    // your code
    // ...

    return null
},
```